# Unknown error in bind_param in mysql

Tags: mysql, bindparam

Hi i got this error message on mysql query which has taken a toll of my time.

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on unknown in ...

Anyone encounter this unknown error before?

How can mysql display the error?

Below is my query:

```
($db->prepare('INSERT INTO program_list(
            PROGRAM_CODE_ID, MONTH, PDATE, HOURS, PUNIQUE, AUNIQUE, 
            EYEBALL, LEVEL, REMARK, REVENUE, TRAINER_ID, CLIENT_ID, ADMIN_ID, UPD_TIME) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)')) || fail('MySQL prepare', $db->error);

$stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssss', $program_code, $month, $pdate, $hours,  $unique, $adult, $eyeball, $lvl,  $remark, $revenue, $trainer_id, $client_id,  $admin_id, $time) || fail('MySQL bind_param', $db->error);
```

I did the echo of the query with variables and able to execute the query successfully on phpmyadmin.

Comment: What is the query? How are you firing it? You really need to mention this.

Comment: and the code is.....

Comment: Show ALL THE ERROR MESSAGE and the code that goes with it. Nobody here is **clairvoyant**

Comment: Although it is probably because the previous `prepare()` failed. I dont suppose you are doing any checks for errors after the  `prepare()`

Comment: If you have gone to Lunch, thats fine, just that  we wont be here when you get back!

Comment: You have 14 binds, but only 13 variables binded.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ, sorry updated the question. Left out the last var just now.